# Is there any built-in type of matrix in CUDA for matrix and matrix-vector operation?

Tags: matrix, cuda, built-in

I want to implement some matrix–vector math. There are vector types like: `float2`, `int2`, but I cannot find any built-in type matrix in CUDA.

Is there a library that suitable for such operations?

Comment: like this: mtrix m; float3 vec;float3 vecOut=m*vec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right to look for a library for matrix data types.  I recommend taking a look at [ArrayFire](http://accelereyes.com/arrayfire).

[Here is the quick reference page](http://www.accelereyes.com/arrayfire/c/page_quickref.htm) with a listing of the supported types.  [Here are the functions](http://www.accelereyes.com/arrayfire/c/modules.htm) you can run with is, which is organized into the categories of data analysis, linear algebra, image and signal processing, sparse matrices, and a bunch of common place algorithms for data indexing, sorting, reductions, visualization, and faster for loops.

Other libraries include CULA or MAGMA (focused on linear algebra), Thrust (targeted at 1D operations), and a host of niche academic libraries.

Disclaimer:  I work on ArrayFire myself.